# How to trigger a file download with text area content when clicking an HTML button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I Found this on GeeksforGeeks and it solves my some part of issue.

```
<script>
    function download(file, text) {
    
        //creating an invisible element
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href',
        'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, '
        + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', file);
    
        // Above code is equivalent to
        // <a href="path of file" download="file name">
    
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    
        //onClick property
        element.click();
    
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
    
    // Start file download.
    document.getElementById("btn")
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Generate download of hello.txt
        // file with some content
        var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var filename = "GFG.txt";
    
        download(filename, text);
    }, false);
```

I tried to make it as per my requirement, i am generating multiple textareas dynamically in a table within  and hiding them, so that for each textarea item shows with download icon when some one clicks on that icon it downloads file with textarea with respective each row content.

```js
                    function download(file, text) {
                    
                        //creating an invisible element
                        var element = document.createElement('a');
                        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(text));
                        element.setAttribute('download', file);
                        document.body.appendChild(element);
                        element.click();            
                        document.body.removeChild(element);
                    }
                    document.querySelectorAll('.btn_mop').forEach(item => {
                        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
                            var text = document.querySelector('.text_mop');
                            var filename = "MOP.txt";
                            download(filename, text);
                        }, false)
                    })
```

```css
                p {
                color: green;
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <style>
        
            </style>
        
                <textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 1st sentence</textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
        
                
                <textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 2nd sentence </textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
        </body>
        </html>
```

It always downloads 1st textarea content even i click on 2nd button, can any please help me how can i get for each download link click it downloads respective textarea content.

Comment: var text is being set to the first instance of .text_mop. You need to select the text within the context of your event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- firstly you are selected all textarea by `SelectorAll` then generated the link without loop through it
- also even if you done a loop that's will generate link for all textarea elements
- if you want to download the textarea before clicked button it's will be better to add them inside a `container` and use `this` keyword
- or use `pervouisSibling`
- also it's will be better to use css instead of `br` tag
- you don't need jQuery because your function already uses Vanillajs

1. **By adding them inside container**

> HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 1st sentence</textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
 </div>
 <div class="container">
     <textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 2nd sentence</textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
 </div>
```

> CSS

```
.text_mop, .btn_mop {
   display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

> JS

```
function download(file, text) {
  //creating an invisible element
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  console.log(element.href);
  element.setAttribute('download', file);
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

var btn_mop = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_mop");
for (var btn of btn_mop) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var text = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("text_mop")[0];
    var filename = "MOP.txt";
    download(filename, text.value)
  });
}
```

2. **by previousSibling property**

> HTML

```
<textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 1st sentence</textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
 
     <textarea class="text_mop" style="display: none;">Welcome to 2nd sentence</textarea>
    <input type="button" class="btn_mop" value="Download" class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" />
```

> CSS

```
.text_mop, .btn_mop {
     display: block;
    width: auto;
}
```

> JS

```
function download(file, text) {
  //creating an invisible element
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', file);
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

var btn_mop = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_mop");
for (var btn of btn_mop) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var text = this.previousSibling.previousSibling
    var filename = "MOP.txt";
    download(filename, text.value)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution, though not as well designed as JS_INF's solution is to add the incrementor to the forEach and then use it to identify the correct .text_mop using querySelectorAll()

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn_mop").forEach((item,i) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    var text = document.querySelectorAll(".text_mop")[i];
    console.log(text)
  });
});
```